# merge dataframe column with another dataframe on single column with different shape of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframe one with a shape of df1 = (1000, 2) and another with shape df2 = (2500, 4) now I am trying to merge them on single common column in both but getting different error on each try.

```
df1 has the following column:
['account_id', 'value']

df2 has the following column:
['account_id', 'price', 'customer', 'label']
```

Note: in df2 account_id can be repeated so thats the reason of (2500, 2)
Here I want df2['label'] to be merged in df1 on account_id

Comment: Can you add data sample and your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if `account_id` in `df2` values are unique:

```
df1['label'] = df1['account_id'].map(df2.set_index('account_id')['label'])
```

If not unique:

```
s = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['account_id']).set_index('account_id')['label']
df1['label'] = df1['account_id'].map(s)
```

Comment: But it gives an error 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but I also got alternative solution,  temp_df = df2.groupby(by='account_id', as_index=False).agg({'label': pd.Series.unique})   and then merge temp_df and df1 on 'account_id'